# How should I unit test a method that only calls FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, security

I have the following methods in my `Authentication` class that is called by my controller. I know the controller can call the `SetAuthCookie` itself, but I'd prefer the additional abstraction.

```
public void FormsAuthSignIn(string loginName, bool rememberMe = false)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginName, rememberMe);
}
```

Just looking at `FormsAuthentication` in the object browser reveals no members that I can use to see if this has worked? Should I build a test controller using the `Authorize` attribute and call a method on it inside my test? What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the only thing to be **unit tested** here is that `SetAuthCookie` was called with the right parameters. You don't need to test `FormsAuthentication`'s logic.

This can be achieved by hiding `FormsAuthentication` behind an interface, and implementing your own stub for it just for tests, that will count calls on methods.
Any mocking framework will help you with this task, while Moles / Typemock Isolator and such will allow you to mock `SetAuthCookie` directly.

Beyond that, IMHO, in this case:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Foo()
    {
        return Bar();
    }

    private int Bar()
    {
        return BarInner();
    }

    private int BarInner()
    {
        return BarInnerer();
    }

    private int BarInnerer()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Only `Foo` should get tested - all the other methods are an **implementation detail**.
Same as in this case - There should be a test for the caller of `FormsAuthSignIn`, that asserts that `FormsAuthSignIn` is called in the right cases.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @seldary's answer, the general way to test any call to a static method is to abstract out that call in your own class, and have an interface to that.

But there is another way (arguably less "pure") if you don't want to modify your production code: some mocking frameworks use hacks to workaround this exact situation, by allowing you to mock calls to a static method.

Look at PowerMock for instance: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/

This is a tutorial to use it: http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/how-to-mock-static-methods.html

(PS: I said "less pure" as Powermock is playing with the classloader and is sometimes not considered a good use of mocking, especially by the London school of mockists)